# Is there an Aggregate per-request or 1 fat aggregate per piece of domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design

My software has an Experiment as the central Entity which contains lots of details about how scientist does what he does. Basically 99% of the functionality happens within the Experiment and there could be thousands of objects stored in it. I have difficulties understanding Aggregates and mapping them to my domain:

- To me it seems like this Experiment object is the Aggregate because it contains all other objects and if something changes - it may propagate to other objects within the same Experiment. So Experiment seems like the right object to keep all the invariants and constraints.
- But then it means the whole app's logic is stored within 1 huge Aggregate

So in DDD do we create a special class per type of request (which is going to reference Experiment) and call it an Aggregate? Then we'll have hundreds of such Aggregates. Or do we treat things like Experiment as an Aggregate and put everything there?

Comment: If your domain is one single aggregate, either it is a very simple domain or there is a flaw in the aggregation.  Not everything that is associated with an aggregate in necessarily within.

Comment: @Christophe, user opens an experiment and there are several pages of details that he has to fill within that Experiment. He can return back to first pages and modify things which have to propagate to next pages. Therefore modification of some objects within this experiment cascade to other objects within same experiment. Do you have ideas of how this can be split into multiple aggregates?

Comment: I see. what you describe here is the user interface. The domain is independent of the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, systems have many instances of aggregates, because they are associated with processes that a business might repeat many times.  A typical example might be something like a reservation book, or a cargo shipment - things that happen frequently, but tend to be mostly independent of one another.

A common design will have one "service" managing many instances of aggregates which are all stored in one shared database.

Aggregates will normally have life cycles longer than a single request.

(To be honest, I don't know of *any* counter examples.  Part of the point of an aggregate, after all, is the management of the lifecycle of a collection of related entities.  If the lifecycle were only a single request long, you'd hardly need fancy patterns to manage it.)

Comment: I see.. I've seen products that had multiple relatively independent pieces of functionality. But there are also products (as in my case) that have a central Entity with which user can work for a long period of time. Such Entities tend to have lots of other objects associated with them. So I wonder whether DDD is simply not suited for such cases. Right now I tend to split the logic between classes that reference Experiment and may modify its internals. These classes then are responsible to keep objects in sync.

Comment: Domain driven design (the design "philosophy") can still be a good idea even if a common pattern ("aggregates") isn't a particularly good fit for your situation.

Comment: That's true. Though I call it simply OOP.

Comment: That's not wrong.  

A fair amount of DDD is just (an opinion on) "OOP done right", where the OO we are talking about is Java circa 2003, and "patterns" are still a relatively new way of talking about implementations.